# Serialized JSON String as Value in JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

I want a serialized JSON string to be treated simply as a string in my JSON when reading it using Jackson.  When I simply escape the serialized JSON string and use it as a value, the serialized string gets treated as part of the JSON and parsed.  Any ideas as to how to go about doing this?

For example:

```
 "{\"payload\":\"{id:\"some-random-id\",version:554471325}\"}"
```

I would like this to be read in memory something like the following:

```
{ payload: "{id:\"some-random-id\",version:554471325}" }
```

However, the parser is trying to read the serialized string as JSON and turn it into the following:

```
{ payload: {id:"some-random-id", version:554471325} }
```

Note the difference between the two outputs.  In one case, the value associated with `payload` is a string, in the other it's a JSON object.  I'm trying to get the former, what I'm getting instead is an attempt at the latter.

Comment: Could you give an example to demo what you want to achieve?

Comment: post your code too?

Comment: I added an example.  I can't paste the code for various reasons.

Comment: Still have no idea what you want to do, I only saw some backslash and double-quotes are removed.

Comment: @JacksonKelley, how do you deserialise this payload? By default it should be read as text. Could you show how do you do that? How do you use `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: The first is a valid JSON string, being just a string of text with embedded quoted. The text is however not valid JSON, and the third `{ payload: {id:"some-random-id", version:554471325} }` is not valid JSON, since a JSON key must be quoted, i.e. it should be `{ "payload": { "id": "some-random-id", "version": 554471325 } }` *(spacing not important)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a terribly worded question, and I apologize for that.  However, I can't come up with a better way of wording it and I'm unable to supply code.  For anyone who stumbles on this and understands what I'm asking, I found a workaround.

I encoded the serialized JSON string to base64 so it was detected by Jackson as a string rather than a JSON object.

The example in the question above becomes:

```
 "{\"payload\":\"e2lkOiJhbnktZXhlY3V...\"}"
```

where `e2lkOiJhbnktZXhlY3V...` is a base64 encoded representation of the string `"{id:\"some-random-id\",version:554471325}"`

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE:*** Answer replaced because question changed.

The examples in the question are not valid JSON. To see what it should be, let's generate it as nested JSON strings:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

Map<String, Object> payloadObj = Map.of("id", "some-random-id", "version", 554471325);
String payloadJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(payloadObj);
System.out.println(payloadJson);

Map<String, Object> rootObj = Map.of("payload", payloadJson);
String rootJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(rootObj);
System.out.println(rootJson);

String rootString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(rootJson);
System.out.println(rootString);
```

*Output*

```json
{"id":"some-random-id","version":554471325}

{"payload":"{\"id\":\"some-random-id\",\"version\":554471325}"}

"{\"payload\":\"{\\\"id\\\":\\\"some-random-id\\\",\\\"version\\\":554471325}\"}"
```

The third line of output is what should have been the text of the first block in the question.

> ```json
> "{\"payload\":\"{id:\"some-random-id\",version:554471325}\"}"
> ```

But as you can see, that text is lacking many double-quotes and backslashes, so it is not valid nested JSON strings, so you can't expect a JSON parser to parse it.

JSON parsers are often lenient, and will do its best to parse it anyway, but don't blame the parser if it gets it wrong. Blame the original text and fix that, rather than trying to parse bad JSON.

---

**Original Answer**

Keys are supposed to be names, or numbers, not entire complex objects, but if you want a JSON as the key in another JSON, just invoke the JSON serializer twice.

*Example*

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

Map<String, Object> data1 = Map.of("foo", 42, "bar", List.of(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8));
String json1 = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data1);
System.out.println(json1);

Map<String, Object> data2 = Map.of("Test", "Hello World", json1, 3.14, "End", "Now!");
String json2 = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(data2);
System.out.println(json2);
```

<sup>*Note: `Map.of()` and `List.of()` are Java 9+*</sup>

*Output*

```json
{"foo":42,"bar":[1,1,2,3,5,8]}
{"{\"foo\":42,\"bar\":[1,1,2,3,5,8]}":3.14,"Test":"Hello World","End":"Now!"}
```

Comment: Ah sorry! I mistyped, I want the serialized string as the *value* not the *key*.  I know how to log it as a string, the problem is, it's being read as JSON when I convert it back into a JSON object in memory, when what I really want is for it to stay as the string representation.  Does this make sense?

Comment: @JacksonKelley Well, first, it would have been nice to know this up front. Second, `"{\"payload\":\"{id:\"some-random-id\",version:554471325}\"}"` is not a valid embedded JSON, because when the string is parsed, it becomes `{"payload":"{id:"some-random-id",version:554471325}"}`, and the value of `payload` is not a valid string, i.e. whoever generated the original string messed up. Fix the code that generated the original string.

Comment: I'm actually not concerned if the string is valid JSON or not since it's a variant of JSON but not real JSON (again, I can't go into more details for the same reason I cannot share code).  Effectively, I'm aware that it's invalid JSON and I want to keep it that way.  That said, even your proposed solution is not working for me.

Comment: @JacksonKelley If it is not JSON, why are you trying to use a JSON parser? Write your parser that understands the format of the file you're reading. This of course assumes that *you* understand the format, but we sure don't.

Comment: I understand that you don't understand the format, which is why I'm apologizing in the answer I provided.  However, whether the string is valid JSON or not is irrelevant to what I was trying to accomplish, as the string should not be parsed regardless of what is actually in the string.

Comment: @JacksonKelley Since it's not a valid JSON string, don't use a JSON parser. When you write **your own parser**, it's entirely up to *you* to implement the *"the string should not be parsed regardless of what is actually in the string"* logic.

Comment: The string encapsulating `payload` is valid JSON, which is why I'm using a JSON parser, the value of the `payload` key is an arbitrary string, just because it happens to look similar to JSON does not mean that it should also be parsed as JSON.

Comment: @JacksonKelley If you parse the text `"{\"payload\":\"{id:\"some-random-id\",version:554471325}\"}"` with a JSON parser, you get the text `{"payload":"{id:"some-random-id",version:554471325}"}`, which is ***not*** valid JSON, it is just some text. To be valid JSON, embedded quotes in the string value of `payload` should be *escaped*: `{"payload":"{id:\"some-random-id\",version:554471325}"}`; which means the original text should have been `"{\"payload\":\"{id:\\\"some-random-id\\\",version:554471325}\"}"`

Comment: As I said, I tried it with your proposed original text and that didn't work for me.  This conversation isn't going anywhere so I'm done responding.  I appreciate your help though! Thank you @Andreas!

Answer (score 0):

Valid JSON is "set of name/value pairs", so what are you missing is the name field, and it's the reason why it's beiing parsed.

For example if the JSON is:

```
{"data": "{\"payload\":\"{id:\"some-random-id\",version:554471325}\"}"}
```

the value of `data` is not going to be parsed.

Btw. the JSON in payload contains key names without quotes (should probably be `{"id": 123, "version": 456}`)

Comment: The name of the field in this case is expected to be `payload`, and I want the value associated with this field to be the string "{id:"some-random-id",version:554471325}" after it's been deserialized by Jackson.